# Can I use a collection initializer with LINQ to return a fully populated collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to rewrite the following code in one line, using LINQ. Is it possible?

```
var to = new MailAddressCollection();

foreach(string recipient in recipients)
{
    to.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
}
```

Something like the following would be ideal. As written it returns multiple MailAddressCollections:

```
var to = recipients.Select(r => new MailAddressCollection() {new MailAddress(r)});
```

Note that these are framework classes, so I cannot rewrite MailAddressCollection to include a constructor argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MailAddressCollection` doesn't have a constructor that takes list of recipients. If you really want to do it in one line, you can write the following:

```
    var to = recipients.Aggregate(new MailAddressCollection(), 
        (c, r) => { c.Add(new MailAddress(r)); return c; });
```

Comment: nice .. but yuck at the same time ;-)

Comment: The brackets aren't quite right, `MailAddressCollection to = recipients.Aggregate(new MailAddressCollection(), (c, r) => {c.Add(new MailAddress(r)); return c;});` works. Good idea though + 1

Comment: @Jodrell: Thanks, fixed. Don't have access to IDE atm.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I have accepted this one as it would work more generally, and does not rely on the Add method of the collection being able to take in a comma separated list. However, I'll just stick with the loop, as this is quite funky! :)

Comment: I like this idea, but before anyone goes down this path, just know that MailMessage.To is read-only, you HAVE to use its methods, none of which accept MailAddressCollection.

Answer (score 3):

There is a 1 line alternative that doesn't use linq which I provide for completeness. Personally I couldn't recommend it due to the unnecessary string manipulation.

It does however provide a terse solution.

```
var to = new MailAddressCollection() { string.join(",", recipients) };
```

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ expression would return an `IEnumerable<MailAddress>`, which cannot be directly converted into a `MailAddressCollection`.

An alternative would be to [Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) the addresses and pass the result to `MailAddressCollection`'s [Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695.aspx) method:

```
var to = new MailAddressCollection();
to.Add(String.Join(",", recipients));
```

Comment: Apologies, just realised my answer is the one line version of yours, +1

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method on `IEnumerable<MailAddress>` which returns a `MailAddressCollection`:

```
public static MailAddressCollection ToAddressCollection(this IEnumerable<MailAddress> source)
{
  var to = new MailAddressCollection();
  foreach(string r in source)
  {
    to.Add(new MailAddress(r));
  }
  return to;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var to = recipients.Select(r => new MailAddress(r)).ToAddressCollection();
```

Comment: good idea if it will be reused, ever. Could be combined with the one line solutions if terseness is the ultimate goal (why). +1

Answer (score -1):

How about this ...

```
var to = new MailAddressCollection(recipients.Select(r => new MailAddress(r));
```

Although, this relies on the presence of a constructor on `MailAddressCollection` (or its superclass) that takes a `IEnumerable<MailAddress>` as an argument. If it is a subclass of `List<T>` [this will be the case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

Comment: `System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection` has no ctor which takes an `IEnumeralbe<T>`.